# Scala: create instance from generic type with private constructor

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I have a class with a generic type parameter and I would like to create an instance of this type using reflection. Moreover, the type has a private constructor. 
Here is a code sample of the problem:

```
class X private (x: Int) {
}
class Y private (y: Int) {
}
abstract class Foo[T](z : Int) {
  var bar : T = createInstance[T](z)
  def createInstance[T](z: Int) : M = {
     ???
  }
}
```

This would allow me to instantiate Foo and access bar:

```
class xFoo extends Foo[X]{
}

class yFoo extends Foo[Y]{
}

var xfoo = new xFoo(5)
println(xfoo.bar.x)

var yfoo = new yFoo(6)
println(yfoo.bar.y)
```

This should print out '5' and '6'.

I have tried using implicit in the following way.

```
def createInstance[T](z: Int)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) : T = {
  val clazz = tag.tpe.getClass
  val ctor = class.getDeclaredConstructor(classOf[Int])
  ctor.setAccessible(true)
  return ctor.newInstance(z).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

However, then I get the error:

```
No TypeTag available for T
```

in line

```
var bar : T = createInstance[T](z)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think that you should be using `scala.reflect.ClassTag` instead of a `TypeTag`.

Comment: Do you really want for `createInstance` to have its own `T` type parameter, different from `Foo`'s?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the super class does expose some method/value you're looking for like:

```
class X private(val x: Int) {}
```

You can extend it like so:

```
import scala.reflect._

class Foo[T](z : Int)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]) {
  var bar : T = createInstance[T](z)
  def createInstance[T](z: Int) : T = {
    val ctor = ct.runtimeClass.getDeclaredConstructor(classOf[Int])
    ctor.setAccessible(true)
    ctor.newInstance(Int.box(4)).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
```

This enables you to call:

```
class XFoo(n: Int) extends Foo[X](n)
println((new XFoo(5)).bar.x)
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the line

Comment: Thanks, but in the line
val ctor = classTag[X].runtimeClass.getDeclaredConstructor(classOf[Int])
you are using classTag[X].
Shouldn't that be classTag[T]?

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was not precise enough. The abstract class Foo should serve as base class for several classes that differ in their type T:

xFoo extends Foo[X]

yFoo extends Foo[Y]

Comment: Fixed and updated. I'm assuming that the class you're extending does expose the method/field you're after though.